# Css Animation to javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
/* JavaScript */

var slides=0;
var array=new Array('back.jpg','banner.jpg','ana.jpg');
var length=array.length-1;

$(document).ready(
    function(){   
        setInterval(function(){
            slides++;
            if (slides<0)
            {
                slides=length;
            }
            if (slides>length)
            {
                 slides=0;
            } 
           document.slide.src=array[slides];
     },4000)
})
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
    <img src="ana.jpg" id="slidess" name="slide" width="200px" height="100px">
   
</body>
</html>
```

Hi guys! Please help me to add css animation to this slideshow! I have tried a lot of possibilities...but no one worked. I have tried to add an animation start class and at the end of the function to replace that class with an animation end class but it didn't work!

Comment: "tried a lot of possibilities...but no one worked" — We can't tell you why unless you show us the attempt. Your question should include a [MCVE]

Comment: what animation you want to add? and you are not adding css animation, you are using javascript. Could you please share what output you want?

Answer (score 0):

As @pirate stated you are using js and you want to use css for animation. You need to refactor your code. Take a look the examples from this [article](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/). and the techniques author used.

This is the nice [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/making-simple-image-slider-html-css-jquery/) explaining how to make simple HTML, jQuery css slider.

What kind of animation would you like to add to your code?